# Writing to a text file with user input and loops

Tags: python, read-write

I am working on a Python 3 program that gets string data from the program user and then writes that data to a text file. An another program that reads the data from a file and then displays that data.

The requirements are that both programs will use loops.  Program #1 should use the signal QUIT to stop running.  Program #2 should run until all of the data is extracted from the file.

I thought I had an understanding of reading/writing to text files in python but I'm completely stumped on this and how to run a loop that will keep going until the signal QUIT. I tried a for loop but that didn't work out so I'm assuming I would use a while loop but not sure how to make that work.

The outlook is expected to the look like the below:

Program #1
Enter a file name: test.txt
Enter a string: Once upon a time
Enter a string: In the west
Enter a string: QUIT

Program #2
Enter a file name: test.txt
Once upon a time
In the west

I'm really stuck on this so if anyone could help out that would be amazing.

Sorry here is the code I have:

```
tf = open("test.txt", "w")
a = input("Enter a string: ")
while a != "QUIT":
    print(input("Enter a string: ")
    if a == "QUIT":
          break
```

Comment: You should show a bit more own effort (=code, even if it has errors) properly formatted in the question. Generally: A while-loop is better for #1.

Comment: In this case I feel like I'd understand better with code than with text.

Comment: Surely `if str == 'QUIT': break` gives you a clue.

Comment: @TimRoberts Using names of builtin elements like "str" should be avoided and therefore not shown in examples or code for beginners.

Comment: It would similarly be amazing if you can provide a code sample.

Comment: Um, @rv.kvetch, that WAS a code example.

Comment: @TimRoberts there is no python code in the question, only pseudo-code which I don't really understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop taking input, we required the *latest* line to be equal to "QUIT". In your code,`a` is not modified after definition, since all subsequent inputs are not stored at all. Instead, we must update `a` for each input:

```py
tf = open("test.txt", "w")
a = input("Enter a string: ")
while a != "QUIT":
    # Current a is not "QUIT"
    # Write a to tf...
    a = input("Enter a string: ")
```

Also, there's redundancy in breaking out of the loop when it already has the same condition for running. It can be avoided by changing the order of input and processing inside the loop (as above).